# Page redirection method - Javascript or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

Which way of redirecting from one page to other is more reliable? I need to to have a link that bring the user to blank page where some php code is executed first(in the background) and then it redirects to the target page. I would like to make this seamless, so the user is not aware that he was redirected. I used javascript for that and it worked fine, but with Javascript disabled it simply won't work. Will php redirection work in this case? Can the header() function be used after some other php code has been executed? All advice appreciated.

Comment: You can fool only children with such a trick. Others will notice a redirect for sure

Comment: PHP is more reliable than Javascript, though why can't you do the processing on the page you're redirecting too? Also, @Shrapnel is correct, the user will definitely be able to see the page change in any way if you have to process data first.

Comment: Well I can't do the processing on that page because it is an external page ergo I cannot run any code there.

Comment: Terrible question title given the actual question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirecting from PHP with `header('Location: '.$URL); die;` is the most dependable redirect you can do (since it works at the HTTP level).

The only catch is that you cannot redirect this way *if you have produced any output* already. This is something that you can avoid by simply thinking through your code flow and designing appropriately, but if push comes to shove you can shoehorn it into an existing code base by utilizing PHP's [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) capabilities (basic example [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.basic.php)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, header can be called after you run php code, just be sure you don't output any text.  Then send a location header.

Answer (score 0):

PHP redirection will work if you didnt send any output before the header. But yes, its easy to notice that you are redirected.

Comment: I wouldnt say its very easy, unless they typed the URL, or studied the anchor for the link they clicked.  Unless the code takes ages to run, you will be instantly at the new URL.

Comment: Yes, you are right, average user wouldnt notice it, and I do not always too. But easily possible to track it. So yes and no. Depends on what is the goal :) if he want to completelly hide this event, he cannot. If only because of user experience, he can.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can execute code with PHP before a redirect. Just be certain to use the right [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for the job. (I assume the default `302` will be appropriate, but you never know.)

This method *will* alert the client's machine of the redirect, but tends to be seamless enough that the average user wont notice.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use AJAX to call a script that processes data, and then when that AJAX is complete you can redirect to the external page?

If all your first script does is calculate data and redirect, without returning any real content, then there's not a lot of point in forcing the page to be synchronously loaded and displayed with a normal HTTP request. I assume you are allowed to use JavaScript since that's in your question.

Comment: In fact, you could return HTTP response code 204 on the PHP side, to make doubly clear that there's nothing to be rendered. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html. In particular, `If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document currently in the user agent's active view.`

Comment: because AJAX stands for is asynchronous JavaScript

Comment: Ah, silly me, I read the question title as actually asking "which is worth using" when the question itself says JavaScript is out. Why the hell ask which to use, then? God.